# How to write repetitive styled components in a cleaner way

Tags: javascript, css, react.js, typescript

I'm using Styled Components for styling and there are many icons defined in the project so in the style file we have this code:

**my-component.styles.ts**

```
import { ReactComponent as CloseIcon } from 'svg/close.svg';
import { ReactComponent as OpenIcon } from 'svg/open.svg';
import { ReactComponent as DeleteIcon } from 'svg/delete.svg';
import { ReactComponent as CheckIcon } from 'svg/check.svg';
...

export const StyledCloseIcon = styled(CloseIcon)`
  width: 20px;
  fill: white;
`;

export const StyledOpenIcon = styled(OpenIcon)`
  width: 20px;
  fill: white;
`;

export const StyledDeleteIcon = styled(DeleteIcon)`
  width: 20px;
  fill: white;
`;

export const StyledCheckIcon = styled(CheckIcon)`
  width: 20px;
  fill: white;
`;
...
```

As it can be seen above, all icons are using the same styling.

And in another component they are used:

```
import {
  StyledCloseIcon,
  StyledOpenIcon,
  StyledDeleteIcon,
  StyledCheckIcon
} from './my-component.styles';
```

and then: `<StyledCloseIcon />`

Is there a way to write it in a shorter way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can declare a new variable like "sameStyles"

```
const sameStyles = `
  width: 20px;
  fill: white;
`;
```

and pass it in as a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) expression

```
export const StyledCloseIcon = styled(CloseIcon)`
  ${sameStyles}
`;

export const StyledOpenIcon = styled(OpenIcon)`
  ${sameStyles}
`;
```

Answer (score 2):

Passing the same style value to each different component is anti-pattern. See https://styled-components.com/docs/basics#extending-styles.

You are supposed to have a base component that has base styles. For example,

```
const Icon = ({ children }) => <div>{ children }</div>;

const StyledIcon = styled(Icon)`
  width: 20px;
  fill: white;
`;

const DeleteIcon = <StyledIcon><DeleteIconSvg/><StyledIcon/>;

export const StyledDeleteIcon = styled(DeleteIcon)`...`;
```